# Eclipse crashing constantly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've installed a freshly downloaded Eclipse EE Luna and started a new workspace, but it's constantly crashing, with no output in the logs when it goes down. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I've checked the following, but nothing further is written after startup:

- workspace/.metadata/.log
- workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rse.core/.log
- workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rse.ui/.log
- workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/0.log

I tried adding the following to eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
  /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
```

and

```
-vmargs
  ...
  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
  -Xmx4096m
```

It still seems to just vanish randomly when I click on things, and most reliably crashes when I clean the project.

Comment: '<install directory>/configuration' is the most likely place for crash logs.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's just crashed again, so seems to be better-but-not-fixed. I'll check for logs there.

Comment: Hmm, nothing useful under there that I can see (`ls -laR | grep -v drwxrwxr | grep -v "\.gif" | grep -v "\.png" | grep -v "\.jar" | grep -v "\.xml" | less`)

Comment: I was facing same kind of problem...See /var/log/syslog..it will definately guide you about cause of crash.also check crash folder in /var/crash...

Comment: Still nothing. No messages in `syslog` and nothing under `var/crash` since yesterday.

Comment: Starting last week my Eclipse Luna has started crashing non-stop too. I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: If your system crashes consistently when accessing Market Place, then this is your issue like mine: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438598

Comment: For me, marketplace was one of the few things that worked - I checked for updates to see if any fixes had been released.

Answer (score 1):

After some poking around, I noticed the following under `Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations`

```
WORKSPACE | (!) NOT AVAILABLE [3.0,)
```

I thought I'd add an external installation to see if that made a difference:

```
Ubuntu Maven | /usr/share/maven 3.0.5
```

So far eclipse now seems to be stable so I thought I'd post this in case anyone else is stuck with the same issue and unable to get any work done.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the solution - still crashing constantly. May have to abandon Eclipse altogether.

Comment: So I finally abandoned Eclipse and went to the free Intellij. It's not bad, even counting that I don't know any of the shortcuts yet..

Comment: And now Eclipse hasn't crashed for a few hours. Perhaps it's a phase-of-the-moon bug..?